# Predicate Logic Derivation Adding Extra Terms Help

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm a bit new to predicate logic derivations and their rules and I'm having a bit of trouble working something out. It is as follows:

> $\forall x Fx \therefore \exists x Fb(x)$

I'm told I cannot use any form of $QN$, so my first step is to use $UI$ on the first predicate to get: $Fb$, but I'm just stuck on what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $b$ is a function?

If so, use UI to get $Fb(a)$, and then use EG to get $\exists x Fb(x)$

Comment: How would I do that from the first predicate?

Comment: I believe b is a term and so is b(x)

Comment: @user2965071 $\forall x Fx$ means **all** objects have property $F$, so that includes object $b(a)$ ( which is an object since $a$ is an object and therefore $b(a)$ is as well). So you can do UI with terms like $b(a)$ just as much as you can do UI with just $a$! Yes, it feels a little weird at first, but it is all in accordance with the rules, and certainly makes sense logically.